# repeated request for wireless password, no wireless connection

Tags: wireless

whenever i try to connect to a wireless network, ubuntu (11.10) asks for the password. when i enter this it thinks for a couple of minutes, then asks for the password again. This happens repeatedly. (it isn't a problem with the wireless modem itself, as i can connect to wireless from the windows 7 opererating system i have running along side ubuntu.

If anyone has any ideas about how to fix this they would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the same phenomenon. I left my computer on overnight and can't even count the number of alerts I've now got stacked on my desktop.

Comment: Should add: this seems to me to be an actual bug, the duplicate alerts at least, and should be reported to launchpad.

Comment: Further adding ... I experience this occasionally, not consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does this when you are entering an incorrect wireless password. Go to the windows 7 computer that is working with the wireless. Click the wireless icon in the taskbar. In the menu that appears, right click on the network that you are trying to connect to, and click properties. Check the box  that says show charachters (this requires administratior priveleges). Type that password into Ubuntu, and it will work. Also try typing the password into a regular text box to see if you have caps lock or anything else turned on that would affect the input of the password. Hope that helps!

Comment: hi, it's definately not an incorrect password, any other ideas? thanks.

Comment: Have you verified this in Windows 7?

Comment: I have the problem erratically, but I verified the password before I started looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read doing my research, the easiest solution was to re-start your wireless card by using the hardware switch. Mine was a PCI card, so no switch. This site helped: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1864163