# Is there a quick way to kill hundreds of alert dialogs?

Tags: command-line

I've got hundreds and hundreds of wireless password alerts on my desktop (possibly related to [repeated request for wireless password, no wireless connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118041/repeated-request-for-wireless-password-no-wireless-connection)) -- while I troubleshoot the source of the alerts I'm wondering if there's a clean way to just cancel them all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `kill $( xprop | grep _NET_WM_PID | grep -o [0-9]*$ )`
(it will kill the next clicked windows' process)